# How to have affiliation without numbering in revtex?

Tags: revtex, affiliation

How do I make affiliation without it being numbered on the last author being numbered too?
I want Author 2 to only have the affiliation of Affiliation 2 and the last affiliation to just be a general affiliation without numbering

[image]

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib,floatfix]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{Affiliation 1}
\author{Author 2}
\affiliation{Affiliation 2}
\affiliation{Affiliation without numbering}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there's a provision for this, but you can hack it:

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib,floatfix]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{Affiliation 1}
\author{Author 2}
\affiliation{Affiliation 2\\Affiliation without numbering}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

It works the same with `revtex4-1`, but I believe you should use `revtex4-2`.

[image]

Comment: Congratulation with sincerity per score 1.0m